# Python: print 4 characters after certain characters in a string

Tags: python, regex

I need from this line:

```
 CR: 0.24%    RU   01.07.2021   CR: 0.44%    TJ   01.07.2021   CR: 0.15%    TJ   01.07.2021   CR: 0.18%    TJ   01.07.2021
```

Get an array like this:

```
['0.24%', '0.44%', '0.15%', '0.18%']
```

That is, get 4 characters after `CR:`

I tried to figure it out with regexes and was able to get one character after `CR:`  My code:

```
print(re.findall(r'CR: (\w+)', string))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try `\w{4}` instead of `\w+`?

Comment: Returns an empty array to me in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `\w+` pattern that matches any one or more letter, digits and underscores (with some connector punctuation and diacritics). It does not match `.` and `%` chars.

You can use

```py
import re
s = "CR: 0.24%    RU   01.07.2021   CR: 0.44%    TJ   01.07.2021   CR: 0.15%    TJ   01.07.2021   CR: 0.18%    TJ   01.07.2021"
print(re.findall(r'CR:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)', s))
# => ['0.24%', '0.44%', '0.15%', '0.18%']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzxMqK/2) and the [Python demo](http://%5B%270.24%25%27,%20%270.44%25%27,%20%270.15%25%27,%20%270.18%25%27%5D).

You might also just get a word after `CR:` with spaces:

```py
print(re.findall(r'CR:\s*(\S+)', s))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzxMqK/1).

*Details*:

- `CR:` - `CR:` string (add `\b` in front if you want to make sure there are no other letters/digits before `CR`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a dot and one or more digits, and then a `%` char
- `(\S+)` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

- `'0.24%'` is 5 and not 4 characters
- `\w` is for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so it doesn't take into account the dot

---

#### Solutions

- `.{5}` for any 5 chars

  ```
  re.findall(r'CR: (.{5})', string) # ['0.24%', '0.44%', '0.15%', '0.18%']
  ```
- `(\S+)` for any amount of non-space chars

  ```
  re.findall(r'CR: (\S+)', string) # ['0.24%', '0.44%', '0.15%', '0.18%']
  ```
- `(\d+\.\d+%)` for a precise match of the expected content, float number with `%` symbol

  ```
  re.findall(r'CR: (\d+\.\d+%)', string)
  ```